# django multiple filter options on queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

We have 2 approach ideas that we are trying to consider here for the Django REST api.

At the moment, we have implemented 1 filter option:

```
class APINewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = APINewsSerialiser

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = NewsBackup.objects.all()
        source = self.request.query_params.get('source', None)
        if source is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(news_source = source)
        return queryset
```

This achieves: `127.0.0.1/news?source=xxx`

Something additional that we would like to do is have other filter options that the user can type in such as `127.0.0.1/news?source=xxx&sourcename=xxx` which would then return them the JSON object with only data that has a source_id of xx and source_name of xx.

Is this possible with the Django REST framework? We have tried to add other options within the method:

```
query_params.get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the filters in a dictionary and then use the dictionary as the filter.  Even better you can create a valid filters that safeguards invalid filters.  Something like below:

```
# {'queryparam': 'db_field'}
valid_filters = {
    'source': 'news_source',
    'source_name': 'source_name',
}

filters = {valid_filters[key]: value for key, value in self.request.query_params.items() if key in valid_filters.keys()}

# So if the query_params is like this: source=xxx&source_name=xxx
# filters value will look something like below:
{
    'news_source': 'xxx',
    'source_name': 'xxx',
}
# **filters transforms the filters to: (news_source='xxx', source_name='xxx')
queryset = queryset.filter(**filters)
```

Or if you don't want to customize it heavily, you can use third party packages like [Django Filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend)

**UPDATE**
If you want to get the multiple values for example: `id=1&id=2`, you can use `getlist`

```
ids = self.request.query_params.getlist('id')
# ids will have the list of id
# ids = [1, 2]
# you can then query the id
queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=ids)
```

**UPDATE 2**
If you want to support multiple filters, you can create a dictionary again:

```
keys = [
    'id',
    'source_name',
]
filters = {}
for key in keys:
    filter = query_params.getlist(key)
    if filter:
        filters['{}__in'.format(key)] = filter

queryset = queryset.filter(**filters)
```

You can add the validation if you want.

Comment: What if I waned to make a request with 2 ID 's ? For instance, I just want to return ID 1 and ID 2. 127.0.0.1?id=1&id=2 ... at the moment this just returns ID 2 @Rieljun Liguid

Comment: @dataviews I have updated the answer for your query.

Comment: this is what I get after making that change: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: I need to be able to combine multiple parameters. So if we wanted to do 2 ID's, but then 1 source name, so return both id 1 and 2 where source name =1 . So for instance ?id=1&id=2&sn=1

Comment: I am still working on your first update. I get an error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: can you show your code? where did you get that `int` from?

Comment: make sure to use `id__in=ids`, not `id=ids`

Comment: yeah, but the sql parameter is id, so why would it be id__in?

Comment: Oh my, if you filter by list, you need to use `__in`, a piece of advice, if you can, please study Django first before DRF.

Comment: If we are having a misunderstanding here, please read carefully my answer.  That should give you the idea of how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!